# Attempting to fix SubQuery that isn't returning expected result set

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm attempting to write a query that will allow me to calculate weekly sales and inventory. The tables are at two different levels of granularity, with sales being calculated on a daily basis, and inventory being calculated on a weekly basis. I'm aggregating the sales portion to the weekly level, and then attempting to include all inventory (to include items that didn't sell in that particular week). I'm not quite sure what I've done wrong, but only the items that have sold in that particular week are returning values despite utilizing a left join.

I've run both the outer query and subquery separately. Both return the individual result sets that I'm expecting. It's when I combine them that I'm having trouble. Subqueries have always been a bit tricky for me, and I've been fighting with this for the last couple of days. I've attempted to place the subquery in the FROM clause, or as a JOIN. I've also attempted running them separately and joining the individual tables. Lastly I attempted running the sales portion as the inner query, and the inventory piece as the outer query, but none of the variations have yielded the expected results.

````
  COALESCE(INV.SKU_NBR,SLS.SKU_NBR)                AS SKU_NBR
, COALESCE(INV.STR_NBR,SLS.STR_NBR)                AS STORE_NUMBER
, CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(SKU_HIER.EXT_SUB_CLASS_NBR AS STRING)), ' ', '-', ' ', TRIM(SKU_HIER.SUB_CLASS_DESC))                     AS SUB_CLASS
, CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(SKU_HIER.SKU_NBR AS STRING)), ' ', '-', ' ', TRIM(SKU_HIER.SKU_DESC))                           AS SKU
, CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(LOCATION.MKT_NBR AS STRING)), ' ', '-', ' ', TRIM(LOCATION.MKT_NM))                             AS MARKET
, CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(LOCATION.RGN_NBR AS STRING)), ' ', '-', ' ', TRIM(LOCATION.RGN_NM))                             AS REGION
, CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(LOCATION.DIV_NBR AS STRING)), ' ', '-', ' ', TRIM(LOCATION.DIV_NM))                             AS DIVISION
, CONCAT(TRIM(CAST(LOCATION.RELO_TO_LOC_NBR AS STRING)), ' ', '-', ' ', TRIM(LOCATION.RELO_TO_LOC_NM))                    AS STORE
, INV.BUSINESS_TYPE                               AS BUSINESS_TYPE
, INV.SUB_TYPE                                    AS SUB_TYPE
, INV.BRAND                                       AS BRAND
, CALENDAR.FSCL_WK_BGN_DT                         AS BEGIN_DATE
, CALENDAR.FSCL_WK_END_DT                         AS END_DATE
, SLS.FSCL_WK_DESC                                AS FISCAL_WEEK_DESCRIPTION
, CALENDAR.FSCL_WK_NBR                            AS WEEK_NUMBER
, INV.OH_DOLLARS                                  AS OH_DOLLARS
, INV.OH_QTY                                      AS OH_QTY 
, INV.OO_QTY                                      AS OO_QTY
, SUM(COALESCE(SLS.UNT_SLS,0))                    AS UNIT
, SUM(COALESCE(SLS.SLS_AMT,0))                    AS SALES
, SUM(COALESCE(SLS.COMP_UNT_SLS,0))               AS COMP_UNITS
, SUM(COALESCE(SLS.COMP_SLS_AMT,0))               AS COMP_SALES
, SUM(COALESCE(SLS.LY_SLS_AMT,0))                 AS LY_SALES
, SUM(COALESCE(SLS.LY_UNT_SLS,0))                 AS LY_UNITS
, SUM(COALESCE(SLS.LY_COMP_UNT_SLS,0))            AS LY_COMP_UNITS
, SUM(COALESCE(SLS.LY_COMP_SLS_AMT,0))            AS LY_COMP_SALES

FROM (SELECT
    INV.SKU_NBR
  , INV.SKU_CRT_DT
  , INV.STR_NBR
  , INV.WEEK_END
  , SUM(COALESCE(INV.OH_QTY,0))       AS OH_QTY 
  , SUM(COALESCE(INV.OO_QTY,0))       AS OO_QTY
  , SUM(COALESCE(INV.OH_QTY,0)*(COALESCE(INV. CURR_RETL_AMT,0))) AS OH_DOLLARS

  FROM `pr-edw-views.INV.SKU_WKLY` AS INV

  JOIN `np-al.data.DR` AS DR
   ON  INV.SKU_NBR = DR.SKU_NBR
   AND INV.SKU_CRT_DT = DR.SKU_CRT_DT
   AND INV.STR_NBR = DR.STR_NBR

  WHERE INV.WEEK_END BETWEEN '2019-07-09' AND 
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE("America/New_York"), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  AND INV.WEEK_END >= DR.EXECUTION_DATE
  GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) AS INV

LEFT JOIN `pr-edw-views.SLS.SKU_SLS` AS SLS         
  ON INV.SKU_NBR = SLS.SKU_NBR 
  AND INV.SKU_CRT_DT = SLS.SKU_CRT_DT
  AND INV.STR_NBR = SLS.STR_NBR

JOIN `pr-edw-views.SHARED.CAL_PRD_HIER_FD` AS CALENDAR
  ON SLS.CAL_DT = CALENDAR.SLS_DT

JOIN `pr-edw-views.SHARED.SKU_HIER_FD` AS SKU_HIER
  ON  SLS.SKU_NBR = SKU_HIER.SKU_NBR 
  AND SLS.SKU_CRT_DT = SKU_HIER.SKU_CRT_DT 

JOIN `pr-edw-views.SHARED.LOC_HIER_FD` AS LOCATION
  ON SLS.STR_NBR = LOCATION.LOC_NBR =             


WHERE SLS.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '2019-07-09' AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE("America/New_York"), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND SLS.SALE_DATE >= DR.EXECUTION_DATE

GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18```

Ultimately the end result I'm looking for is to retrieve all the sales for every item sold in a given week, as well as the inventory for those items and any other items that have not sold. Right now the query is only returning the correct sales values, but incorrect inventory values for all items, whether they were sold or not. I appreciate any guidance I can get! Thanks!
````

Comment: Your group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 should be group by 1, 2, 3, 4 as remaining columns are aggregate columns.

Comment: Its always good to ask question with minimum problematic part of your query as biiiiiig query often decrease the interest of jump in to the query for analysis. Where as necessary small part of query with some sample data and expected output make things easy and clear.